# What is exacly ms_nfp_launchargs in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

If we want to get to the run parameters of the application we write:

```
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ms_nfp_launchargs", out value);
```

What is exacly `ms_nfp_launchargs`? Where is it defined? What is the background of that value?

I know that it is a key, but I want to know more.

Answer (score 1):

It is used by NFC functionality. It allows you to pass parameters to your app when launching from NFC tag.
WP 8 translates the parameters passed from the NFC tag into this special-purpose URL parameter named ms_nfp_launchargs.
So it can also help you detect if your app is launched normally or launched from an NFC tag within the OnNavigatedTo method of the app's startup page.
(test if NavigationEventArgs.Uri contains "ms_nfp_launchargs")

Comment: Thank you for elaborating but this is what I already know. I would like to know where is stored that collection which holds this key... is it map? Are there other keys stored there?